# How make real modal window

Tags: jquery

i searching some example of a real modal-window for browser in JQuery. For "real modal-window" i mean about that window that opened not allow action to main window (click, scroll etc) until not is clicked a button (OK, ABORT etc)in it.
I have found much examples on internet of modal window but all this examples when modal window is opened allow event (click, scroll etc) on main window and so not ok for me.
I hope to find someone that can help me in this sense. Is ok too some good tool/script/plugin (too not free) for to have it.

Comment: You sure? [Bootstrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) don't allow interaction with the "background" while the modal is visible. Same applies to [Lighbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) and [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net) for example as well.

Answer (score 1):

to block clicks, you have to create a mask behind your modal (using CSS) and add a stopPropagation() onclick

in jQuery it would look like

```
$(".mask").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

then to avoid any kind of scroll you may look the scrollable element with $('body, .scrollable').css('overflow', 'hidden'); if the only scrollable element is your body

then restore to the default value after this (can be done by storing the current overflow value to the dom element)